# Error when Installing OpenCV 2.4.11 in Centos

Tags: opencv, gcc, centos6

I followed the instructions online to install OpenCV 2.4.11 in Centos. But I got an error in the step of `make && make install`.

Here it is:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/libstdc++.a(ctype.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `vtable for std::ctype<wchar_t>' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/libstdc++.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.11] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my `libstdc++.a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, I think the problem is that your static libstdc++ is compiled without the -fPIC option, so ld doesn't want to make a shared object with it.

The -fPIC option generates position independent code that has extra information that lets it be mapped into different memory addresses without having to change (this is why ld is complaining when you try to make a shared object using code that is not position-independent).

You can fix this by getting (or building) a libstdc++ that is built with -fPIC.

Comment: Actually I have installed gcc 4.8.1 and don't know why it went into the directory of gcc 4.4.7.  So I just removed that libstdc++.a, and it works.

Comment: But now it is stuck at 65% during the installation. The problem is c++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.

Comment: This is a vague error, but just a shot in the dark: how much memory and swap space do you have?

Comment: I'm  actually using the Parallel virtual machine, which has 992MB memory and 1024MB swap space.

Comment: I would increase those and try to build again.

Comment: Yes, I will try. Any suggestion on how much memory and swap space should I have?